# what is the problem in this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code that retrive json data and tries to parse it , but it doesn't work . why ?

```
function News()
{
var q;
if(qN=="" || qN==null)
    q="gaza";
else
    q=qN;
var txtNews="";
var url='http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json?q='+q;
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){

    alert("test");
    $.each(json.articles, function(index, elem){
        alert(elem[index].author);      
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You can't do an Ajax request to a different domain. The Same Origin Policy forbids it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: why does it work for  url='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+q+'&max-results=7&v=2&alt=jsonc';
 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what does it do? I can almost guarantee it doesn't work because you're trying to make a cross-site request. See if the API supports JSONP.

Then try this:

```
function News()
{
var q;
if(qN=="" || qN==null)
    q="gaza";
else
    q=qN;
var txtNews="";
var url='http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json?q='+q+'&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){

    alert("test");
    $.each(json.articles, function(index, elem){
        alert(elem[index].author);      
        });
    }); 
}
```